# Dynamically retrieve information, if a given SObject field is system read-only

Tags: apex, permissions

I have apex code that dynamically creates SObject records based on configurations (metadata type records). The code needs to evaluate on-the-fly, if the Sobject field that should be "put" (`sObjectRecord.put(fieldName, fieldValue`) is from a read-only system field or a regular, writable field.

The code will run in system context, so this is not about permissions but about database enforced read-only fields.

Typical fields that should be recognized as read-only are:

- CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, etc
- CreatedById, LastModifiedById, etc
- All auto-number fields (custom and standard, such as Order.OrderNumber)
- All formula fields
- The standard id fields (`Id`)

My current code works like this:

```java
public Boolean isWriteable() {

    // always return false for formula and autonumber fields
    if (fieldDescribe.isCalculated()) return false;
    if (fieldDescribe.isAutoNumber()) return false;

    // get all read-only system fields: they are not permissionable, accessible but not update/writable for current user
    if (!fieldDescribe.isPermissionable() && fieldDescribe.isAccessible() && !fieldDescribe.isCreateable() && !fieldDescribe.isUpdateable()) return false;

    // always return false for compound fields and other fields that are not intended to be written
    switch on fieldDescribe.getType() {
        when address { return false; }
        when base64 { return false; }
    }

    return true;

}
```

So far, the debug logs show me satisfying results. Anything I forgot? Please help me to improve the code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to post this in the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) forum, instead.

Having said that, I think you're code looks good to establish if the field is writable, however when you're populating the field, you need to be aware of a lot of stuff. the [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe) is helpful here:

- Put your logic to populate the field in a `try cactch` block, because there are lots of gotchas.
- If you're populating fields, make sure you're not overfilling the fields (i.e. if a text field can take 255 chars, and you fill it with 256 chars, or for number fields, you're checking that you're not exceeding the number of digits. You can use `getDigits()` / `getPrecision()`
- if you're populating a picklist, make sure the value that you're populating it is allowed. You can use the `getPicklistValues()` and the `isRestrictedPicklist()`
  methods from the `DescribeFieldResult Class`
- You also want to make sure that you're populating dependent picklists correctly. use `isDependentPicklist()`

Comment: Are you sure, that the `put(fieldName, value)` operation will already throw an execption? I think, most of validation will only be performed on Database calls (insert, update).

Comment: try this, and update the object and field name.... put(text_field__c,   'f'.repeat(Schema.SObjectType.YOUROBJECT.fields.text_field__c.getLength() + 1),);

Comment: Yes, I had validation rules in mind. They only fire on the actual database operation.

Comment: I also tried your code and it works without any exceptions.